# SQL: Finding user with most number of comments

Tags: sql, mysql

I need to find out the user who has posted the most number of comments. There are two tables 1)users(Id, DisplayName) 2)comments(Id, UserId, test) . I have used the following query

```
Select DisplayName from users INNER JOIN (Select UserId, max(comment_count) as `max_comments from (Select UserId, count(Id) as comment_count from comments group by UserId) as` T1) as T2 ON users.Id=T2.UserId
```

However, this returns to me the Display Name of the user with Id = 1 rather than what I want. How do I work around this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT TOP 1
 U.DisplayName,
 COUNT(C.ID) AS CommentCount
FROM
 Users AS U
 INNER JOIN Comments AS C ON U.ID = C.UserID
GROUP BY
 U.DisplayName
ORDER BY
 COUNT(C.ID) DESC
```

Comment: Thanks ... I was using MySql and had to use 'LIMIT 1' instead of 'TOP 1'